# How to change wordpress header stylesheet

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm running into a bunch of problems with a 'premium' WP theme I purchased. The developers aren't being a very big help besides 'it should work' and 'it works for other people' so I'm just trying to figure it out myself.

Chrome's Dev tools have been my biggest friend so far. The problem I am having with this theme is that my style changes aren't being applied. Now there are three different locations where I could do this. One is style.css another one is custom.less and the 'quick css' box that comes packaged with the theme. Neither of these options work - sometimes some changes will be applied from style.css - but most of the time my changes are not applied. I have started digging in the source (parent) files and started changing those and again - no change.

Now I found out with the help of chrome's devtools that the header file refers to the stylesheets with version numbers. The moment I removed the version number from fw-style-css all my changes were fed through immediately. Now I would like to know where in WP I will have to start digging to get to the header part where I can change the stylesheet details. I already looked up header.php but it refers to  and I have no clue what to do after this.

The website in question is just a testing environment until I have everything sorted out, then I will port it over to my main site. The website in question is http://dev.amyranth.com/
[image: Header]

Answer (score 1):

If the stylesheet files aren't directly linked in the header.php file, then the stylesheets must be included via the [wp_enqueue_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) function. Example:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media ); ?>
```

The fourth parameter is "version" which is most likely what you saw in the source code. You should change this every time you make a change to the stylesheet because it will help with browser caching by forcing the browser to download a new version of the file. Otherwise, it will assume that the old cached copy of the stylesheet is still valid.

Update:

The best way would be to do what @ViperCode suggested and create a new stylesheet, then add it to the theme with wp_enqueue_style.

In fact, the very best way would be to [create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) which extends the premium theme you are trying to customize. That way your changes would be maintained separately and would not be overwritten by theme updates.

Comment: I found a whole stylesheet called functions.wp-styles.php that seems to be all about enqueueing stylesheets.. however I have no clue what to do now. I don't see any direct handles to specific stylesheets. functions.php is empty :\ I don't know much about php at all so this is difficult.

Comment: Can you share one or two lines from functions.wp-styles.php?

Comment: This seems to be about registering a stylesheetfunction wp_register_style( $handle, $src, $deps = array(), $ver = false, $media = 'all' ) {
 global $wp_styles;
 if ( ! is_a( $wp_styles, 'WP_Styles' ) ) {
  if ( ! did_action( 'init' ) )
   _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( __( 'Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the %1$s, %2$s, or %3$s hooks.' ),
    '<code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>', '<code>login_enqueue_scripts</code>' ), '3.3' );
  $wp_styles = new WP_Styles();
 }

 $wp_styles->add( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
}

Comment: I think the code you found is part of the the WordPress core files. Try searching again for "wp_enqueue_style" but limit the search only to the theme folder located at "wp-content/themes/NAME_OF_THE_THEME" - everything you want to change should be in that theme folder.

Comment: This is what I get if I search in my theme for that handle: http://prntscr.com/6w9t5r

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Perhaps the plugin author has done something else to add the stylesheets. That's a bit odd, the standard way to include stylesheets is with wp_enqueue_style.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to search your theme's directory for the function name `wp_enqueue_style`

Comment: Or alternatively, enqeue your own custom style sheet that overrides the theme's style sheet.